# Focus textbox and position cursor on page load

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

So I want to set the cursor position to the end of the textbox after the page is loaded. I have this code for the JQuery:

```
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/ichord/Caret.js/master/src/jquery.caret.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
            var textbox = $('#MessagesBox');
            textbox.focus();
            textbox.caret('pos', textbox.val().length);
    });
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="MessagesBox" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"
style="resize:none" ReadOnly="true" Width="300" Height="200"></asp:TextBox>
```

What am I missing? Do I need to set something in the code-behing as well?

Comment: Please show your aspx code for the textbox.

Comment: that seems fine -> [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fHolg6DZBpUizfQN2rrO?p=preview)

Comment: @PraveenPaulose -  This is the code for the textbox:

<asp:TextBox ID="MessagesBox" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" style="resize:none" ReadOnly="true" Width="300" Height="200"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: is the problem with focus() or caret()?

Comment: is the textbox within another server control, a.k.a is the ID of your textbox really MessagesBox on the client-side?

Comment: your textbox has a different id once it get rendered, add ClientIDMode="static" to avoid that

Comment: do yourself a favor and don't lean on RAZOR to create your text box...

Comment: That doesn't look like razor

Comment: @JuanC. - Unfortunately setting ClientIDMode="static" doesnt work, nothing happens as before.

Comment: do you get any errors on the console?

Comment: @JuanC.- Nope, compiles fine and runs, but without the desired code effect.

Comment: Check the rendered html, make sure the id is what you expect and is unique, then adjust your selector as necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var el = $("#MessagesBox");
    var elemLen = el.value.length;

    el.selectionStart = elemLen;
    el.selectionEnd = elemLen;
    el.focus();
});​
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked! (TextBox looks like this now:
<asp:TextBox ID="MessagesBox" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" TextMode="MultiLine" style="resize:none" ReadOnly="true" Width="300" Height="200"></asp:TextBox>)

Comment: @kisbovan93 It is working because you set ClientIDMode to static, not anything else. You had 2 options 1. either set the ClientIDMode to static or use the ClientID.

Comment: @PraveenPaulose I think the problem was not the textbox id, but the javascript code to set the caret at the end

Comment: Check the Plunker that was put as a comment by @Jonesy. It works with the same code. It then has to be the id issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that the ID of the textbox will not remain MessagesBox since it is a server control. ASP.NET changes it and gives it a Client ID. You will need to use the Client ID or use another attribute to identify the textbox in jquery. You can verify the control's name by using Inspect element from Chrome.

You could use this to identify the control by its Client ID

```
var textbox = $("#'<%=MessagesBox.ClientID %>'");
```

Alternatively, you have access to the control's client ID on the server side which can then be used to create and register your script from the server.

Comment: It is really annoying, but unfortunately still doesnt work after adding it.

Comment: Remove the ReadOnly attribute and check

Comment: When you look at the control using Inspect element what is the id shown in Chrome?

Comment: It says id = "MessagesBox"

Comment: Have you set the ClientIDMode to static?

Comment: I think it should be this way var textbox = $("#<%=MessagesBox.ClientID %>");